# How to install specific-package-version (when multiple version available from multiple repos) in Archlinux?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, package-management, pacman

[image]

- I'm trying to install `nim-2.0` in my system.
- When I try to install with `pacman -S nim` or `yay -S nim` It direclty installs the `nim-1.6....` version.
- How to install package when there is multiple versions available.
- Perhaps,  better question might be: How to specify the `repo` (in this case `Extra-Testing`)

Comment: Have you enabled `Extra-testing` in your pacman configuration?

Comment: As @muru said. Here's the link: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Official_repositories

Comment: @muru, @ajgringo619, Thank you for the response. Is adding following 2 lines: `[Extra-testing]`
`#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` into `/etc/pacman.conf` sufficient? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @GaridZ. that shows a commented out `Include` line. It should look like the examples for [`multilib`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Official_repositories#multilib) or [`gnome-unstable`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Official_repositories#gnome-unstable). Also, I don't know if it's case sensitive, but the repo headings I have seen have all been lower case (so `extra-testing`)

Comment: Remember: if you enable the testing repo, you enable it for all of its packages, for better or worse. In my experience, packages don't stay long in testing, so I'd wait until it gets merged into stable.

Comment: @ajgringo619, thanks, I installed [`choosenim`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages?O=0&K=choosenim) and it installed the `nim-2.0`, which seems better option this particular case for me

Comment: @muru, Thanks! for the tip of lower-upper-case

Answer (score 0):

you can download the source file [from the arch gitlab](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/nim/-/blob/main/PKGBUILD) then pacman -U path/to/newpackage but, it's not recommended due to dependencies issues